# Parse unstructured json in golang

Tags: json, http, go, goland

Is there any solution to parse an unstructured json(text) data?
below is a sample response of a web requst that i want to parse and access data (the inner list)

```
res,err := http.Get("url_of_server")
```

```
[[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "text": "sample text",
        "user": {
          "user_id": "1",
          "username": "user1"
        },
        "created_at_utc": "2022-12-20T16:38:06+00:00",
        "status": "Active"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "text": "sample text",
        "user": {
          "user_id": "2",
          "username": "user2"
        },
        "created_at_utc": "2022-12-01T10:15:00+00:00",
        "status": "Active"
      }
],
"{"code": "hsdvnkvuahudvhafdlfv",
  "is_updated": true}", 
 null
]
```

what i want to get is:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "text": "sample text",
        "user": {
          "user_id": "1",
          "username": "user1"
        },
        "created_at_utc": "2022-12-20T16:38:06+00:00",
        "status": "Active"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "text": "sample text",
        "user": {
          "user_id": "2",
          "username": "user2"
        },
        "created_at_utc": "2022-12-01T10:15:00+00:00",
        "status": "Active"
      }
]
```

in python it is possible by easily using `res.json()[0]`

I have tried using `json.Unmarshal()` to a map and also struct but does not work,
i don't know how to get rid of this part of response:

```
"{"code": "hsdvnkvuahudvhafdlfv",
  "is_updated": true}", 
 null
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? There's no such thing as "unstructured JSON", JSON is structured by definition. It might help if you show the things you tried and explained how/why they didn't work.

Comment: @Adrian Yeah, you are right. the whole response is not a json, I want the json part in inner list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a type for the items:

```
type Item struct {
    ID   string `json:"id"`
    Text string `json:"text"`
    User struct {
        UserID   string `json:"user_id"`
        Username string `json:"username"`
    } `json:"user"`
    CreatedAtUtc time.Time `json:"created_at_utc"`
    Status       string    `json:"status"`
}
```

Declare a slice of the items:

```
var items []Item
```

Declare a slice representing the entire JSON thing. The first element is the items.

```
var v = []any{&items}
```

Unmarshal to `v`. The `items` slice will have the values that you are looking for. The second and third elements of `v` will contain the values you want to ignore.

```
err := json.Unmarshal(data, &v)
```

[Run the code in the GoLang PlayGround](https://go.dev/play/p/Orx_YbUfxeU).

Comment: the problem is that the second section of the response has a double quotation around itself, I mean this one: 
``` "{"code": "hsdvnkvuahudvhafdlfv",
  "is_updated": true}" ```

Answer (score 3):

Go's standard JSON library is not as flexible as others when it comes to dealing with unexpected or uncontrolled input.

A great alternative is tidwall's [gjson](https://github.com/tidwall/gjson).

Example code with gjson:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "github.com/tidwall/gjson"
)

const textInput = `[[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "text": "sample text",
        "user": {
          "user_id": "1",
          "username": "user1"
        },
        "created_at_utc": "2022-12-20T16:38:06+00:00",
        "status": "Active"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "text": "sample text",
        "user": {
          "user_id": "2",
          "username": "user2"
        },
        "created_at_utc": "2022-12-01T10:15:00+00:00",
        "status": "Active"
      }
],
"{"code": "hsdvnkvuahudvhafdlfv",
  "is_updated": true}", 
 null
]`

func main() {
    jsonBody := gjson.Parse(textInput)
    fmt.Println(jsonBody.Get("0"))
}
```